# Has anyone successfully made a FeatureLayer from a view in DB2 and ArcSDE 10?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, javascript, features, db2

Lately it seems like every new ESRI feature fails for me - I must be cursed. I'm testing the use of a FeatureLayer to see if helps display and query features using the JavaScript API 2.0.

This layer was registered with ArcSDE from a view. The data is in a DB2 database. We have used the view for a long time in a MapService on our server.

I copied the MapService MXD to a new file and published it as a FeatureLayer. As a MapService it shows up in ArcCatalog and can be previewed. It also shows up in ArcGIS Service Manager. The MapService doesn't show up in the ArcGIS Services Directory page. If I enter the URL in a browser, it returns an error. If I try to add the layer to a JavaScript API map, it raises an error **"missing } in XML expression"** in Firebug for the script arcgis?v=2.0, line 52.

Is there anybody who's used a FeatureLayer successfully? Any pointers or hints?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to contact support. You have to know this by now, but DB2 users aren't exactly the majority of the esri sde community.

Comment: I just started working with DB2 a couple of months ago and boy did I learn that fast. Unfortunately ESRI support is 0 for 5 on our environment.

Comment: Make that 0 for 6. So far support has said "our samples work" using their data. Looks like another non-working ESRI feature, at least in DB2. Before ArcGIS 10 we managed multiple graphics layers with scripts, so we'll stay with what works.

Comment: Have you tried going farther forward? Version 2.4? Who knows if there may be better fix in the newer versions...

Answer (score 1):

This issue, along with some others, made me roll back from version 2.0 to 1.6 of the API. When 2.1 came out, I gave it a shot and I am able to make a FeatureLayer show up. It still requires creating the symbols on the client, but it can be done with a ClassBreaksRenderer.